# Load csv file and save into sql table

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I have csv file (file) and structure of file like this:

```
Amount;P_price;Ean;Number;Name;DPH;certifikate;o1;o2;ZC
0;168,00;8806333394584;E1347;MISSHA Gel;21;106;0002;0001;290
0;156,80;8806336488488;E1357;MISSHA Lotion;21;106;0002;0001;271
0;123,20;8806584752571;E1367;MISSHA Mist;21;106;0002;0001;213
```

I want to load all rows without first, where i have names of columns...This values i want to save into sql table...I know how i write into sql, but i need to know how i could load value from each row to this variables:

```
Amount
P_price
Ean
Number
Name
DPH
certifikate
o1
o2
ZC
```

The filepath i have into: string file;
Have you any ideas?

Comment: No, i want insert first row..after that second row....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that's the format and there will never be any `;` in the actual values, then you can use a quick and dirty method:

```
foreach(String line in File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1))
{
    String[] columns = line.Split(';');
    String amount = columns[0];
    String P_price = columns[1];
    //etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks...and it is possible to not save first row?

Comment: skip the first iteration? :)

Answer (score 0):

please tried with below link and let me know any help need

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

`in sql server`

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[csv]
        FROM 'C:\Users\...' --file path
        WITH
        (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        ERRORFILE = 'C:\Users\file\...',
        TABLOCK
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself
http://www.filehelpers.com/ will help you to work with the csv files

Example:

File with CSV:

```
10248|VINET|04071996|32.38
10249|TOMSP|05071996|11.61
10250|HANAR|08071996|65.83
10251|VICTE|08071996|41.34
...............
```

Data transfer object:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class Orders
{
    public int OrderID;

    public string CustomerID;

    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
    public DateTime OrderDate;

    public decimal Freight;
}
```

Reader:

```
FileHelperEngine<Orders> engine = new FileHelperEngine<Orders>(); 

// to Read use: 
Orders[] res = engine.ReadFile("TestIn.txt");
```

And than:
[image: usage]

For you:

```
[DelimitedRecord(";")]
[IgnoreFirst(1)] 
public class RootObject
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public string P_price { get; set; }
    public object Ean { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DPH { get; set; }
    public int certifikate { get; set; }
    public int o1 { get; set; }
    public int o2 { get; set; }
    public int ZC { get; set; }
}

FileHelperEngine<Orders> engine = new FileHelperEngine<RootObject>(); 

// to Read use: 
Orders[] res = engine.ReadFile("TestIn.txt");
```